# How to get list of rows of pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I get a list of row lables in pandas?

I have a table with column labels and row labels. To return the column lables I use the dataframe "column" attribute.
It is possible to return the list of column labels with the attribute columns, but i couldn't find similiar attributes for rows.

Comment: you mean `df.index`?

Comment: You're looking for `df.values`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work. `df.index.values`
This returns index in the form of numpy array `numpy.ndarray`, run this `type(df.index.values)` to check.

Answer (score 5):

Try the attribute `index`

```
df.index.values
```